# How to access Google Cloud billing data cost forecast, using node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, billing, forecast

I'm able to extract aggregated and itemised billing data from **Google Cloud** using **BigQuery**, against exported billing data. I'd like to be able to query the *forecast billing data* that is shown in the console, but I can't find this in any API or referenced anywhere for use in the billing data export. Is it possible?

Comment: The data are not yet available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The forecasted billing data is not available to export to BigQuery. The forecast costs can only be [viewed as graphs](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#cost-forecast) from the Cloud Billing console.
- A forecasting model can be built on the past data for analysis using [BigQuery ML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/bigqueryml-web-ui-start).
- Google Data Studio also can be used to forecast costs as shown in this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/visualize-gcp-billing-using-bigquery-and-data-studio-d3e695f90c08).